# How can i set the phonegap image path

Tags: javascript, cordova, path, camera

Pretty easy question. How can I set the path where phonegap saves the images from the camera?
So that I can just tell it to save on the SDcard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Camera API does have parameter to choose the path of the picture. You can only choose picture encoding type (png/jpg) and if you want base64 return of uri of the file.

You can use the FILE api to move the image where you want after it's taken.

Comment: unfortuante, but at least i know it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function save(){

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}



    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("pic.jpg", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
    }

    function gotFileWriter(writer) {

        var photo = document.getElementById("image");
        writer.write(photo.value);

    }

    function fail(error) {
        console.log(error.code);
    }
```

Comment: use comments not answers to say things like that. And no need of code, he asks if using camera api of cordova/phonegap there is or not a parameter to set the path.

Comment: I use this: navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI });

Comment: what is "image"? is it an img tag?

Comment: <img src="" id="image"/>